# How can the Visual Studio 2008 Build Command Line be seen?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-build-professional

When I am in Visual Studio I hit the F5 to do a build.
Is there a way to see the MSBUILD command line being executed?

Inside of Visual Build Pro the build fails but when run from Visual Studio 2008 (hitting the F5) it succeeds.

Here is the command line used inside of Visual Build Pro:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe C:\Code\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET.vbproj /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /v:detailed /p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\"  /p:InstallUrl="https://www.benesys.net/benesys.net/TotalEducationTest/"  /p:ApplicationVersion=1.0.1.198  /p:ProductName="Total Education TEST"   /p:PublisherName="BeneSys, Inc."  /p:UpdateRequired="True"  /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=1.0.1.198
```

Comment: You are targeting a specific project in your example. If you have more than 1 with cross dependencies it may be that you need to target the actual solution file with MSBuild.

Comment: Please use your profile for links to your personal sites.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can see the command line being executed within Visual Studio, but you can set the verbosity of MSBuild to **diagnostic** within Visual Studio and then compare the output with output produce by Visual Build Pro.

```
Tools > Options > Project and Solution > Generate and execute > "MSBuild verbosity" to Diagnostic
```

To set the verbosity of MSBuild in command line add `/v:diag`

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe /v:diag C:\Code\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET\EduBenesysNET.vbproj /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /v:detailed /p:PublishDir="\\BSIIS3\c$\DATA\WEBSITES\benesys.net\benesys.net\TotalEducationTest\"  /p:InstallUrl="https://www.benesys.net/benesys.net/TotalEducationTest/"  /p:ApplicationVersion=1.0.1.198  /p:ProductName="Total Education TEST"   /p:PublisherName="BeneSys, Inc."  /p:UpdateRequired="True"  /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=1.0.1.198
```