# Long build time in VS2008 Mobile Application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, compact-framework, opennetcf

Lately testing my application becomes painful. When I hit F5 in debug configuration VS' building time increased. it takes 1-2 minutes to finish building. Even a slight code changes makes me mad :/.

My application uses OpenNETCF and Open Sans font for labels etc. When I started to develop this application it was 100-200kb and now its 800kb+. I don't know what makes the files size that big.

I searched how to trace log of build process in VS2008 but I couldn't find any resource. Is there a way to log building process in Milli Second results ?

Comment: `/v:diag` didn't give enough info? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

Comment: It is probably the ncb getting fragmented.  Normally happens when you use external libs.  That is probably why they switched to SQL server on 2010.  Try deleting the ncb.

Comment: what is ncb, how to delete

Comment: @rene I couldn't figure where to pu v:diag

Comment: google /v:diag vs2008 gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779773/how-can-the-visual-studio-2008-build-command-line-be-seen

Answer (score 0):

As @rene told me I figure out how to see logs while building.

This link helped me out : [How can the Visual Studio 2008 Build Command Line be seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779773/how-can-the-visual-studio-2008-build-command-line-be-seen)

and also While building Mobile application VS has "platformverificationtask" which is :

> Platform Verification Task (PVT) is a post-build validation step to catch the unsupported PMEs before they can result in a runtime exception.

It makes building process longer. to disable pvt use this link : http://www.morkeleb.com/2011/02/21/disabling-platformverificationtask-for-compactframework-projects/